# How to move guides with artboard?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, selections

If I have multiple artboards and I want to move a board, how can I select both the board and it's guides and move them at the same time?

Currently I can move the board with its content, but can't select the guides and hence have to manually set them again.

Comment: Hi rjtkoh, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: @Scott "Yes, we can!" Obama

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a frequent problem, however sometimes one wants to move an artboard with all the guides.

The solution is not perfect, but worked for me:

Before I drag the artboard I "release the guides" -

<kbd>View</kbd>-><kbd>Guides</kbd>-><kbd>Release guides</kbd>

After I dragged the artboard I "make the guides" from converted shapes
 (+ select the lines again):

<kbd>View</kbd>-><kbd>Guides</kbd>-><kbd>Make guides</kbd>

Comment: *Technically* this isn't moving guides. This is releasing guides, moving paths, then creating guides. I know that's just semantics and this is a great solution.

Answer (score 4):

Before setting your guides, switch to the Artboard Tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>), then drag out your guides. You'll notice when you do this that the guides will finish at the edge of the artboard, instead of running off over the entire work area.

When you move your artboard, the guides will travel with it.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Illustrator you can change between global and artboard rulers. So to move artboard with guides you switch your type: view/rulers/gloval or artboard.

Answer (score 0):

1. Group guides
2. Lock other layers
3. Select all guides
4. Copy all guides
5. Right click, select second paste option with drop down
6. Select paste on all artboards. Enjoy !!!