# Illustrator: When rearranging artboards, how to make guides follow?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, guides

I have some artboards that I want to rearrange in order to even out the spacing between them. The trouble is, when I **Rearrange All Artboards** Illustrator completely ignores my guides, leaving the guides in their original positions and rendering them useless, as they are no longer positioned relative to the artwork.

[image]
[image]

↑ "Move Artwork with Artboard" is ticked.

Layers are not locked.

And yet, this is the result (artwork not shown, only layout and guides):

[image]

As you can see, there are artboards to the left now missing their guides, and guides to the right that have gone astray from their artboards.

Why Illustrator's default behavior is to ignore the guides while moving the artwork is beyond comprehension, but that is what's happening.

[Here is a question similar to mine](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54017/), but that question is not specifically about "rearranging", and the answers for that question have not worked for me. **Release Guides** is greyed out. Dragging out my guides while using the Artboard Tool did not work either. **View > Rulers > Change to Global Rulers** also did not work.

Comment: Just checking: You're aware you have to `View > Guides > Unlock Guides` then *select the guides*, then `View > Guides > Release Guides` right? Just choosing to release guides does nothing if the guides aren't first selected.

Comment: @Scott Thank you. No, I was not aware of that. Or if I knew at one point, I had forgotten. Probably because I almost always leave my guides *unlocked*, but all on their own dedicated guide layer - and I will just toggle the locking of the layer instead of locking/unlocking guides. I've just found it easier not to have to track down which layer a guide is on, by keeping them all together. But in getting out of the habit of locking/unlocking the guides themselves, I stopped paying attention to the guide lock feature. And it seems *in this case my guides were locked*. Care to post as an answer?

Comment: I tend to do the same for guides (just make a layer).. much easier to manage. Reworded comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Released* guides are merely paths. Those paths *should* move with artboards if that option is ticked, since paths are art.

One must...

- `View > Guides > Unlock Guides`
- then **select** the guides
- then `View > Guides > Release Guides`

The result should be standard (unfilled, unstroked) paths where guides were.

Merely choosing to release guides does *nothing* if the guides aren't first *unlocked* and *selected*. Release Guides only works on *selected* guides.

Yes, logically, you'd think Release Guides just releases all guides in one step, whether or not they are locked and/or selected, but it simply doesn't work that way.